# Cannot overcome SSL certificates in Firefox 47.0.2 using geckodriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, ssl, geckodriver

I am trying to overcome the SSL certificate for accessing a web page on Firefox 47.0.2, 48 using the geckodriver and selenium-standalone-server-3.0.1 jar. The code I am using is opening the browser but does not accept the certificate.

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                               System.getProperty("user.dir") + aProperties.getProperties().getProperty(aProperties.getOsName() + ".geckoDriverPath"));
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
            profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
            cap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
            cap.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);
            cap.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", true);
            cap.setCapability("marionette", false);
            driver = new MarionetteDriver(cap);
```

I found a way to set the Profile and the capabilities when required. But I am stuck at accepting the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196) is the original bug. This was an issue on both Firefox's side and GeckoDriver. Not sure what version of GeckoDriver you are using, but the latest ([0.15.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.15.0)) that should be fixed. Also note that the Firefox bug was not fixed in version 47 or 48 gotta get Firefox 52.0 which is the stable release as of (3/7/2017)

Comment: Hi, I am using GeckoDriver v0.14.0.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in confirming. Upgrading worked!